# Convert .data file to .csv

Tags: dataset, data, csv

I'm using a data called  'adults.data', I need to work with that data as a '.csv' file. Can anyone guide me on how can I change the format?
I tried opening the file in excel and then save it as csv, but the new file contains only one column containing all the '.data' columns.

Comment: You could take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762762/convert-data-file-to-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- One way is to convert .data file to excel/csv using Microsoft Excel which provides an option to get external data (use Data tab --> from Text). Check this [video for demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10CBtXcymfU)
- Other way you can utilize python to read .data files and directly work with dataframes

  ```
       import pandas as pd
       df = pd.read_csv("adults.data")
  ```

  (OR)

  ```
       df = pd.read_table("adults.data")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use pandas to read the file and then export it to an excel form as following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.data", sep=",", header=None)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

You could read more [here](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/read-data-files-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

1. Before loading the data make sure check the file format.
2. Load the required libraries
3. First read the excel file using 'pd.read' function
   save the file into csv format using function 'to_csv'

. example:

```
pp = pd.read_excel('paul_palmer.xlsx')


pp.to_csv('paul_palmer.csv', index=False)
```